# Deleting federated objects - IBM db2 PLSQL

Tags: plsql, db2, plsqldeveloper

I am working with IBM db2.

I have some scripts which are implemented like this:

```
begin
execute immediate 'CREATE WRAPPER MY_WRAPPER';
execute immediate 'CREATE SERVER SERVER390 TYPE DB2/ZOS VERSION 7.1 WRAPPER MY_WRAPPER AUTHORIZATION "APP_USER" PASSWORD "secret" OPTIONS (DBNAME 'remotedb');';
execute immediate 'CREATE USER MAPPING FOR PUBLIC SERVER SERVER390 OPTIONS (REMOTE_AUTHID ‘APP_USER', REMOTE_PASSWORD ‘secret');';
execute immediate 'CREATE NICKNAME ASSIGN for SERVER390.db_schema.ASSIGN';
end
```

I want to be able to check and delete everything (wrapper, server, user mapping, nickname assign), in case it exists (avoind errors if the objects don't exist).

What would be the best way?

Comment: The corresponding information is stored in the following system catalog views: SYSCAT.WRAPPERS, SYSCAT.SERVERS, SYSCAT.USEROPTIONS, SYSCAT.NICKNAMES. So, just process a result set of the corresponding cursor and run a series of generated `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP ...'` statements.

Comment: Can you give further help with this please ?

Comment: I tried to do itone by one by doing a if exists (select * ...) the execute imediate 'drop ...')... but i am not sure how to implement this in a better way, so could you be so kind to help?

Comment: Use this [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/CWorNF3l) as an example. A generated `DROP` statement there returns an expected error, of course, but the example demonstrates an idea.